# Python handling any exception gives error KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, exception

Here's the code:

```
try:
    input() # I hit Ctrl+C
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    input()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Answer (score 2):

please, be explicit, when you want to catch `KeyboardInterrupt`:

```
try:
    input() # I hit Ctrl+C
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
except KeyboardInterrupt :
    print 'ok, ok, terminating now...'
```

Comment: So if I want to handle any exception's text, but I don't know every exception's name, how do I do this?

Comment: @JoeDoe see the code above, `except KeyboardInterrupt` catches Ctrl/C, and you may handle all other exceptions in the next `except` statement. Or do you want to do something completely different?

Comment: @JoeDoe you don't, as that's not explicit (which exceptions will you handle? What do you expect your code to raise? Etc.). [Explicit is better than implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). In general, however, if you catch [`BaseException`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy), all other exceptions should be caught also.

Comment: I want to the code would handle any exception. Because I didn't know about KeyboardInterrupt, handled only Exception and then that error showed up. So I want to handle any exception `as e` and `print(str(e))`

Comment: @JoeDoe catching **every** exception is not a very good idea, you won't be able to interrupt your program with `Ctrl/C` for one.

Comment: Thank you. I'll remember it

Answer (score 0):

`KeyboardInterrupt` is not an [`Exception`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.Exception) but only a [`BaseException`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.BaseException), so your `except` is not handling it:

```
>>> issubclass(KeyboardInterrupt, Exception)
False
>>> issubclass(KeyboardInterrupt, BaseException)
True
```

Handling a `BaseException` gives you access to any exception, but is discouraged:

```
try:
    # ...
except BaseException as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Comment: So if I want to handle any exception's text, but I don't know every exception's name, how do I do this?

Comment: You would do `except BaseException:` or just `except:`, but both is discouraged as, among other things - like in your example - you can no longer interrupt your program. It is better to be as explicit as possible and if needed add more exception types you want handled.

Comment: In case `except` I can't get the text of exception. I'll try `BaseException`, thanks